# jquery tablesorter unclosed tag on IE11

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm using the jquery tablesorter, on IE11 on a clients system (version 11.0.9600.18161) and also on Chrome (version 50.0.2661.102 m) the tables will not sort by clicking on the header, after looking at the Console in IE I see:

```
    HTML1509: Unmatched end tag.
```

I've looked at the generate HTML and can see this:

```
        <colgroup class="tablesorter-colgroup">
        <col style="width: 8.5%;">
        <col style="width: 9.8%;">
        <col style="width: 7.6%;">
        <col style="width: 6.8%;">
        <col style="width: 22%;">
        <col style="width: 8.6%;">
        <col style="width: 9.2%;">
        <col style="width: 12.9%;">
        <col style="width: 14.1%;">
        </colgroup>
```

The source is the same for all browsers, although this is the same in Firefox, firefox does not report any issues and everything works, but this looks wrong to me, why aren't there any closing 'col' tags?

Here is my call to tablesorter:

```
          $(objLocTable).tablesorter({theme:'blue'
                            ,showProcessing:true
                                ,widthFixed:false
                                   ,widgets:['zebra'
                                             ,'scroller']
                              ,widgetOptions:{scroller_fixedColumns:2
                                                  ,scroller_height:400
                                             ,scroller_upAfterSort:true
                                            ,scroller_jumpToHeader:true}})
                               .tablesorterPager({container:$('.pager')});
```

I tracked down an error in the function 'sortNatural', if either a or b isn't a string the routine errors, but there is no error handling so the sort isn't completed.

I can't tell you why either a or b wouldn't be a string, looking at the data set they should be, but single stepping in debugging shows that one of the parameters is null and this screws up the function.

I've fixed the problem by surround the function content with a try / catch clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-col-element) & the [HTML w3.org HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-col-element) definitions, the `<col>` tag has **no end tag**.

> Tag omission in text/html: No end tag.

To get around this problem, leave tablesorter's [`widthFixed` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widthfixed) as `false` (default setting), and set the column widths using CSS - target class names in the header, or use `nth-child` in the css.

Oh, and you can [report this issue to IE](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/).

Comment: I think this should be the chosen answer. Also, if there really was a problem I'd report the error to the creator of tablesorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/. It's his fault if it doesn't work in IE

Comment: widthFixed wasn't set, so it would be using the default.  I have set it to false now, but I still ge tthe same problem.  And the console still reports unclosed tags,  I have checked the HTML and there are no other unclosed tags.  And the colgroup and col tags are still present.

Comment: @JaredBeach LOL I maintain a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), and it really is not a problem with tablesorter. @SPlatten, check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/r25tag6k/3/) no `<col>` are found.

Comment: @SPlatten just a joke haha